# How can I create a search with filters in Angular/Express/MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, angular, express

I am trying to mimic the functionality of the right sidebar of [this example](http://pro-theme.com/wordpress/autozone/vehicle-listings/) for my Angular site.

I don't know what this is called, or even how to go about it on the front end or back end!

My assumption:

1. Create a form with values coming straight from the DB and only show the desired parameter (i.e. db.collection.find(query, {parameter: 1}) which will be called to update each time a user modifies the form. Additionally, the results would also be updated on selection (I have over 100MB of documents, returning ALL of them would be troublesome, how can I limit the number of documents returned to let's say 20 or 50 (user input?) and paginate it (1000 documents returned / 50 per page = 20 'pages')
2. Each input that is selected, a { 'field' : value } would be returned -- but I am not sure how to control an empty value (i.e. what if a user doesn't pick a fuel type or transmission range?)

How do I go about designing such a feature correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your query, use limit statement:

```
    var options = { "limit": 20 }
    collection.find({}, options).toArray(...);
```

2) you can validate user empty input (for eg. [with express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator)):

```
req.checkBody('postparam', 'Invalid postparam').notEmpty()
req.getValidationResult().then(function(result) {
    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
      res.status(400).send('There have been validation errors: ' + util.inspect(result.array()));
      return;
}
```

and based on result choose default value/pass error/render ask page for user

Comment: how can I use express-validator to delete empty fields ( { field1: "" }), and pass the nonempty fields to the query?

Comment: check custom validators on express-validator